# Issue on mobile device: HTML tag not working

Tags: html, css, mobile, cross-platform, compatibility

I have a very simple web application which displays DIVs as menus and then, at the bottom, there is a "confirm" button.
Confirmation is initiated via tag `<A>`

```
<a href="Shop.asp" id="ConfirmButton" name="ConfirmButton">
    Submit Order <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
</a>
```

So, this application (and "confirm" button) works perfectly on any browser that I have used for the test (Chrome, Firefox,  Edge, Opera).

It seems that on mobile webbrowser (Android and IOS webbrowser) no action when the user tap/click over `<A>` tag.
On Windows all works but on mobile nothing happens.

`<A>` tag is defined on CSS

```
::after, ::before {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button > a {
display: inline-block;
width: calc(50% - 0px);
padding: 12px;
background-color: #D10024;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 700;
-webkit-transition: 0.2s all;
transition: 0.2s all;
}
a:hover, a:focus {
    color: #D10024;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
a:focus {
    outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
.button { //on DIV style
    visibility: visible;
}
```

There are no DIVs in front of the button.
I tried to intercept the `onClick` and `onTap` events of the button but nothing happens.

Is there a way to identify what blocks the execution of `<A>` tag and to check the **compatibility** of the HTML / Javascript code on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

Hovers aren't possible on mobile devices.

Try :active in CSS or onclick in Javascript.

or ontouchstart to mimic the effect of hover.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_touchstart.asp

Also, I found an article for you :

https://medium.com/@mezoistvan/finally-a-css-only-solution-to-hover-on-touchscreens-c498af39c31c

Comment: No result on all "mobile events" over that '<A>' tag

Comment: As I said, hovers aren't possible on mobile devices, because the device does not know if you are hovering over using the touch screen. There's no mouse. To mimic the effect of hover, you have to use onclick.

Comment: onClick, onTap, onTouchstart, onTouchmove, ..... this TAG not listen